# How do find out which object a name is resolved to at runtime?

Tags: python, introspection

To patch an object one needs to use the right path from the call site.  This is sufficiently fiddly to get its own section in the [unittest docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#id6).

Sometimes when this is a pain to figure out I'd rather just set a breakpoint right before calling the object to patch and then inspect it to see what is actually looked up.  Then I could exit the debugger and patch the right object.  This feels an easy problem, akin to `which` on the shell, but I can't think how to do it.

Condensing the example from the docs:

a.py

```
class SomeClass: pass
```

b.py

```
from a import SomeClass

@breakpoint # resolve SomeClass into b.someclass here
def fn():
    s = SomeClass()
```

> Now we want to test some_function but we want to mock out SomeClass using patch() [...] If we use patch() to mock out a.SomeClass then it will have no effect on our test[...].

> The key is to patch out SomeClass where it is used (or where it is looked up). In this case some_function will actually look up SomeClass in module b, where we have imported it. The patching should look like:

```
@patch('b.SomeClass')
```

How do I get `b.SomeClass` from the debugger?

[Note that the imports are easy in the example given.  But sometimes things are sufficiently deep or convoluted it can take a bit of puzzling to get it right.  A separate problem is expressing `b` correctly from the test function, but assuming everything is in packages the canonical form should work.]

Comment: I'm guess you want something more useable than `os.path.basename(sys.argv[0]).removesuffix(".py")` right?

Comment: @JonSG whilst that will work in this example it's not a general solution... unless I'm being really thick and the answer is always 'the module name.thing'.  In which case this is a non-question and I've just confused myself.

Comment: Will it not be either `import foo` and `foo.SomeClass` or `from foo import ..` in which case, it is `modulename.SomeClass`? Even if it distills down to that, it seems like a valid question to me still

Comment: I don't see how using the debugger would be any simpler than just using your editor's find function to locate the name you plan on patching.

Comment: I think I'm overcomplicating this one.  I'll try a bunch of examples tomorrow.  If it really is as simple as all that I'll self-answer for the next duffer who overthinks it.

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is patching things inside a class, you can actually patch methods *inside* the class in their original module, and it will just work.

So, let's suppose in your example you want to patch `Subclass.__init__` - you can do just `patch("a.Subclass.__init__")`.

Now, if you want to mock the whole subclass, a way to do exactly what you are asking for is to mock it's  `__init__` method, just as I wrote, but insert a `breakpoint()` in it - so that you can manually inspect and find out about `b.Subclass`.

Here is a shell session where I issue the shell and PDB commands to find it out:

```
(env311) [gwidion@fedora tmp92]$ cat >a.py
class SomeClass: pass
(env311) [gwidion@fedora tmp92]$ cat >b.py
from a import SomeClass

def fn():
    s = SomeClass()

(env311) [gwidion@fedora tmp92]$ cat >c.py
from unittest.mock import patch

import b

with patch("a.SomeClass.__init__", lambda self: (breakpoint(), ...)):
   b.fn()
   pass

(env311) [gwidion@fedora tmp92]$ python c.py
--Return--
> /home/gwidion/tmp92/c.py(6)<lambda>()->(None, Ellipsis)
-> with patch("a.SomeClass.__init__", lambda self: (breakpoint(), ...)):

(Pdb) l
  1     from unittest.mock import patch
  2  
  3     import b
  4  
  5  
  6  -> with patch("a.SomeClass.__init__", lambda self: (breakpoint(), ...)):
  7        b.fn()
  8        pass
  9  
[EOF]
(Pdb) down
*** Newest frame
(Pdb) up
> /home/gwidion/tmp92/b.py(4)fn()
-> s = SomeClass()
(Pdb) l
  1     from a import SomeClass
  2  
  3     def fn():
  4  ->     s = SomeClass()
  5  
[EOF]
(Pdb) __name__
'b'
(Pdb)
```

(It is important to have something in the same scope as the `breakpoint()` is, after the breakpoint call proper, otherwise the debugger won't allow us to interact with that scope and will jump straight to the calling one - that is why I made the lambda return `(breakpoint(), ...)`, instead of just `breakpoint()` )

Comment: Thank you; I think I've somehow seriously overcomplicated importing in my head.  But I never thought of using `l`; certainly easier than digging in the venv.